# Android Emulator error messages "Emulator XX = xxx"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After update android studio to 3.0 beta 4, I encountered with some error message when I launch emulator(s).
see `right side` of this image:
[image: emulator error message]

where are these errors come from? and how can I solve it?

Comment: stupid question but i have to ask it, did you restart studio ? windows ?

Comment: Delete your existing emulator and recreate new one.

Comment: @YamenNassif yes, it's happened after update android studio and install android emulator module from sdk manager

Comment: @james no, but emulators runs correctly, but on some cases some of them go to offline mode and I must restart it again.

Comment: well i suggest to use some other emulators such as bluestacks or genymotion